# No folder icons in Firefox bookmarks manager

Tags: firefox, bookmarks, firefox-profile

Since updating Mozilla Firefox 21 to 22 the Bookmarks Manager doesn't show folder icons anymore. This makes managing bookmarks an inconvient process.

What can be the reason that I lost my folder icons in Firefox? I have already tried disabling all Firefox add-ons and reinstalling. I don't want to remove my entire profile, I would lose too many settings.

[image: 123]

Comment: i have the same issue with Firefox v22 and yes, it makes for a very bad experience. Seems this may be intentional and I have filed my complaint with Firefox. I suggest you do the same: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=625317

Comment: *update* here's a possible solution ... if you have the Firefox addon "Bookmark Favicon Changer" installed, then try uninstalling it. That worked for me. Apparently FF v22 is has broken compatibility with this addon, which is causing the bookmark folder icons to disappear. here's the original link https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mozilla.support.firefox/b8hN3BpCE_0